# rails 3 js code error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my `process_form.js.erb` file:

```
$('#write_offs_table > tbody').append('<tr class="list-line-<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %>" id="<%= @write_off.id %>">                                           
                                           <td class="name"><%= @write_off.date %></td>
                                           <td><%= @write_off.user.name %></td>
                                           <td><%= @write_off.status %></td>
                                           </tr>');
```

it doesn't execute and chrome shows me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#write_offs_table > tbody').append('<tr class=list-line-<%= cycle("even", "odd") %> id="<%= @write_off.id %>">\                                     
                                       <td class="name"><%= @write_off.date %></td>\
                                       <td><%= @write_off.user.name %></td>\
                                       <td><%= @write_off.status %></td>\
                                       </tr>');
```

I used the `\` character to tell javascript that it continues on a new line.

Comment: / doesn't change anything but the idea about new line, I put it all in one line and now it's ok, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I think you need the backslash \ instead of the forward slash /.